# Is there a neat closed form expression for $\frac{x^2}{\beta} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x/\beta)^n}{(n+2)! (n+1)}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

The original aim is to solve a differential equation of the form $$y_2(x) = \frac{1-exp(-\frac{x}{\beta})}{x}.$$ I tried a Taylor series expansion and got $$y_2(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x/\beta)^n}{(n+1)!\ }.$$
Then I tried integrating this expression twice to arrive at the form 
$$\frac{x^2}{\beta} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-x/\beta)^n}{(n+2)! (n+1)}$$
 I'd like to get a nice closed form expression of this term, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.{x^{2} \over \beta}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 
{\pars{-x/\beta}^{n} \over \pars{n + 2}!\pars{n + 1}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{x/\beta}\ >\ 0}} =
{x^{2} \over \beta}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 
{\pars{-x/\beta}^{n - 2} \over n!\pars{n - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{x^{2} \over \beta}\,{\beta^{2} \over x^{2}}
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 
{\pars{-x/\beta}^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n - 2}\,\dd t =
\beta\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 
{\pars{-xt/\beta}^{n} \over n!}\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\beta\int_{0}^{1}\pars{\expo{-xt/\beta} - 1 +
{x \over \beta}\,t}\,{\dd t \over t^{2}} =
x\int_{0}^{x/\beta}{\expo{-t} - 1 + t \over t^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\, &
x\bracks{\left.-\,{\expo{-t} - 1 + t \over t}\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ x/\beta} -
\int_{0}^{x/\beta}\pars{-\,{1 \over t}}
\pars{-\expo{-t} + 1}\,\dd t}
\\[8mm] = &\
-\beta\expo{-x/\beta} + \beta - x
\\[2mm] &\
- x\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\Lambda}
{\expo{-t} - 1 \over t}\,\dd t -\
\underbrace{\int_{x/\beta}^{\Lambda}
t^{\color{red}{0} - 1}\expo{-t} \,\dd t}
_{\ds{\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \Lambda\ \to\ \infty}{\LARGE\to}\ \Gamma\pars{0,{x \over \beta}}}}\ +\ \int_{x/\beta}^{\Lambda}{\dd t \over t}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Gamma\pars{a,z}}$ is the
>   [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E2).

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.{x^{2} \over \beta}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 
{\pars{-x/\beta}^{n} \over \pars{n + 2}!\pars{n + 1}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{x/\beta}\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\beta\expo{-x/\beta} + \beta - x +
x\,\Gamma\pars{0,{x \over \beta}} +
x\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}\dd t}
^{\ds{=\ \gamma}}
\\[2mm] &\
- x\ \underbrace{\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}\bracks{%
\ln\pars{\Lambda}\pars{\expo{-\Lambda} - 1} + \ln\pars{\Lambda \over x/\beta}}}
_{\ds{-\ln\pars{x \over \beta}}}
\end{align}

---

$$
\implies \bbx{-x + \gamma x + \beta - \beta\expo{-x/\beta} +
x\,\Gamma\pars{0,{x \over \beta}} +
x\ln\pars{x \over \beta}}
$$

> $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
>   [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.E3).

Comment: I can follow this step till the penultimate line. I tried to integrate-by-parts by taking the numerator as the first function and the denominator as the second. I don't see how the last line follows.

Comment: @SoumikGogolPurkayastha I just add some details which answer your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfy says that

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{n + 2}}{(n + 1) (n + 2)!} \\\quad = - \gamma x + x - e^x - x \log(-x) - x Γ(0, -x) + 1
$

where
$Γ(0, -x)$
is the incomplete gamma function.